# c# Equality operators on null type

Tags: c#, equality, nul

on the c# 6.0 tutorial it says: Lifted equality operators handle nulls just like reference types do. This means two null values are equal:

```
Console.WriteLine ( null == null); // True 
Console.WriteLine((bool?)null == (bool?)null); // True
```

While I tried first express in IDE, it won't compile, complains [image]

[image]

Not sure what is the reason?

Comment: Which IDE is this? That code compiles fine for me.

Comment: seems related to the IDE .. works fine in LINQPad

Comment: As it seems to work with current Compilers, it seems yours is not running properly on C# 6 or later.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I am using Rider 2017.3 how to find out which c# version compile I am using? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in the IDE? As when I run it, gives me the output true.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the IDE, yes. I'm surprised it lets you run it at all if it's giving you an error when compiling. This code compiles with the C# 2 and C# 5 compiler as well as with Roslyn.